# Conditional or arbitrary fill in ggridge (R)

Tags: r, ggridges

I'm trying to shade the area under the curve to the right of a given x, which is not the same for all the density plots, but it varies according to the level of y. For example,

[image: A quick sketch of what I'm trying to do]

On the package vignette I can only find solutions to shade the areas according to quintiles, but it's not what I'm trying to do (I have cutoffs generated from some modelling).

Any ideas?

```
library("ggplot")
library("ggridges")

diamonds %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = x, y = cut)) +
   geom_density_ridges()
```